# Prove that the graph has at least 200 vertices

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

In the company, each employee has at least 50 acquaintances. It turned out that there are two employees who are familiar only through 9 handshakes (i.e. the shortest way of communication consists of 8 intermediate people). Prove that at least 200 employees work in this company.

My attempts of solution are straightforward. Consider a graph in which the vertices are people, and the edge denotes the familiarity of people. Each vertex has 50 edges and there are 2 vertices whose shortest distance is 9. We enumerate the path. Note that the vertices connected to the first vertex can not coincide with the vertices connected to a 5 or 6 vertex. Similarly, vertices connected to 5 or 6 vertices can not intersect with vertices connected to 10 vertex. Otherwise, the graph would have a path shorter than 9. Thus there are at least 150 vertices in the graph. However, I do not know how to prove about 200 vertices.

Thank you for any help or ideas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider one of the employees at the end of the $9$-long handshake chain, $a$. His acquaintances form a set, $D_a(1)$, of at least $50$ people. Their acquaintances who are not in $D_a(1)$ form a set, $D_a(2)$, which might be small but of course is not empty. The next group of acquaintances is $D_a(3)$ know someone in $D_a(2)$ but no-one in $D_a(1)$, and thus continue with these sets, all non-empty, until we reach $D_a(9)$, of which the other employee in the opening premise, $b$, is a member.

Each member of $D_a(3)$ knows $50$ people who are in either $D_a(2),D_a(3)$ or $D_a(4)$. Each member of $D_a(6)$ knows $50$ people who are in either $D_a(5),D_a(6)$ or $D_a(7)$. And each member $D_a(9)$ knows $50$ people who are in $D_a(8),D_a(9)$ or the potentially-empty  $D_a(10)$.

These non-overlapping groups of at least $50$ people each, together with $a$ and $a$'s $50+$ acquaintances  $D_a(1)$, give at least $201$ people in total.